# How to add Google analytic to a "web-view" android app , and the app is without any buttons

Tags: webview, google-analytics

How to add Google analytic to a "web-view" android app 
Note that :  My app hasn't any buttons

Answer (score 0):

If your web-view app is hosted at some http(s) server, use GA as normal, if you host apps files locally as some parts of native app's build files, such as PhoneGap app, here is the solution [Using Google Universal Analytics with PhoneGap Apps](http://www.blastam.com/blog/index.php/2013/07/ga-universal-analytics-phonegap-mobile-apps/)

Comment: But how can I know the difference between the app, and regular users on the browser?